# Groovy XML MarkupBuilder does not create root <?xml .... ?>

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

I am using XML MarkupBuilder to generate XML files

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.*

....

def xmlObj = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(xmlObj)
xml.book("id":21){
    name('bookname')
}
```

and I get the output:

```
<book id='21'>
    <name>bookname</name>
</book>
```

how can I make it generate the root xml tag as well?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can add xml declaration with MarkupBuilder too:

```
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(xmlObj)
xml.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")
xml.book("id":21){
    name('bookname')
}
```

Comment: So I am guessing what I did is not the right way to do it:
    xmlObj.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")

Answer (score 12):

You need to add it yourlsef

```
def xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{
        mkp.xmlDeclaration()
        task {
            id(_Id)
            name("clean")
        }
    }
```

Comment: To elaborate, `mkp` is available in builder closures to access a [MarkupBuilderHelper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilderHelper.html), which includes the `xmlDeclaration` method.